# SQL Server Reporting Upgrade

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Can I install SSRS 2017 on SQL Server Standard 2014?
Also, can I use SQL Server product key for the SSRS 2017?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can host the data on a Instance that isn't 2017. As per the system requirements, you need SQL Server 2008 SP4 or later (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55252).

You need a SQL Server 2017 Product Key for SSRS 2017 though. You can't use a 2014 key.

Comment: So, if I want to install SSRS 2017, then I have to but a SQL Server 2017 license?

Comment: Buy* Yes. This has always been the case. For example if you are hosting your Data Engine on one Server and SSRS another, then that's 2 sets of Licences. if you were to then install the SSAS Instance on another server again, that's another set of licences. SQL 2017 follows the same licensing model as 2012 onwards; 1 licence per CPU core, sold in 2 core packages (with a minimum of 4 to be purchased).

Comment: Thank you very much, you've been very helpful.

Comment: You'll need to run the SQL Server 2017 Setup to find your key.  More info: [How to find the product key for SQL Server 2017 Reporting Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/find-reporting-services-product-key-ssrs)

Comment: The OP didn't have a 2017 key, @ashleedawg , they wanted to use a 2014 key for a SSRS 2017 instance (that doesn't work).